# Unable to get transcribe text in webhook - twilio

Tags: twilio

**My use case**

My case is that i'm making a bot for listening podcast in which user will make call to twilio number and bot will ask what type of podcast would you like to listen then record for 10 seconds

when recording finish, it say user to please wait while we are finding podcast

I want that recording in my webhook with transcribed text so i will figure out caller mood and find appropriate podcast mp3 file from my database and play to caller

**Issue I'm facing:**
what issue I'm facing is it is not getting recording url in recording action nither getting transcribe text in transcribed callback

have a look of my webhook responses:

Screenshots:
[image][image][image]

Comment: Are you getting callbacks to your transcribe callback at all? Note that transcribe callbacks are made asynchronously to the rest of the call.

Comment: yes getting callback

Comment: Can you edit your question with an example of the parameters you are receiving when you get a transcribe callback request?